# Eclipse syntax highlighting preferences save and restore

Tags: eclipse, ide, syntax-highlighting

I spend some time customizing the colors for syntax highlighting in Eclipse (Java, JSP, HTML, CSS, etc.) but whenever I try to export these settings via File|Export|General|Preferences and reimport them, the settings never completely get imported back. Some colors are restored and others are left unchanged, leaving me in an 'in between' state - very frustrating.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede, by the way.

Has anyone found a reliable way to save and restore Eclipse syntax highlighting settings?

Comment: What a mess eclipse generates with coloring!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this.

I just wanted to mention beforehand that I did try to start with a fresh Eclipse install, export the preferences to a `.epf` file, change just one single setting, export again, and compare the files. To my surprise, trying to import settings from a minimal `.epf` file did not work reliably either.

The solution that worked for me was to copy these files: `{Eclipse workspace directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/*.prefs`

I tried a fresh Eclipse install on another machine and after copying those files over, all my settings were restored perfectly.

Comment: Excellent this worked for me. Only other thing I would add is to make sure you back up your old files first just in case.

Comment: Great, worked even when switching from Eclipse@Windows on Eclipse@Mac

Comment: Vote down because by copying all `*.pref` files, even in the same version, you can mess things up. There are settings which have nothing to do with syntax coloring in these `*.pref` files, like workspace location, jre settings, etc. You cannot just copy-paste, instead, color codes should be line-based separated.

Answer (score 72):

The solution was to copy SOME - not all - of the files from `{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/*.prefs` into my other workspace.

In particular (per the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse thread):

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs = Syntax Coloring    
org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs = Text Editors
```

Copying other files caused things to break.

There are a couple of notes to add:

1. I had to copy the aforementioned pair of files several times before I got the correct syntax coloring.

   Be sure to close the workspace, if it's open in Eclipse, before copying the files.

This worked with Eclipse Helios.

Comment: If you had also chosen a different font or font size, you can carry these to your new workbench by also copying org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs and org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs. Tested from Android Developer Tools to Eclipse Kepler 4.3 in Feb 2014.

Comment: Worked for me also when copying these files from eclipse Luna 4.4.x to a SpringToolSuite (eclipse Kepler 4.3.x) installation.

Comment: Worked for me just overwriting the file `org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs` on Mars.1 (4.5.1)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be a little more fine grained on what you migrate, the syntax highlighting rules are the lines starting with semanticHighlighting on workspace-indigo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs

Doing this, I was able to migrate my syntax highlighting from Helios to Indigo

Answer (score 8):

I'm using JBoss Developer Studio 10 with the Eclipse Neon 4.6 engine.

All `.prefs` files are inside this path:

```
/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.sett‌​ings
```

> **Update:** I found a similar structure on  this path too:
>
> `\RedHat\JBossDev\studio\configuration\.settings`
>
> It's my IDE folder plus `\configuration\.settings`

I recommend search for `org.eclipse.*ui*.prefs` instead `*.prefs` to refine your result.

The principal config files are:

- org.eclipse.**jdt**.ui.prefs

  - Java Syntax Color Settings
- org.eclipse.ui.**editors**.prefs

  - Text Editor Settings
- org.eclipse.**cdt**.ui.prefs

  - Formatter Settings
- org.eclipse.wst.**jsdt**.ui.prefs

  - JavaScript Syntax Color Settings
- org.eclipse.jst.**jsp**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**css**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**html**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**json**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**dtd**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**xml**.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.wst.**xsl**.ui.prefs

---

If have a problematic workspace:

1. `Copy` the files above
2. `Create` a **new workspace**
3. `Copy and Replace` that files in your **new workspace**

This will recover perfectly your custom editors color settings. For me worked very well.

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse CDT stores 'Syntax coloring' in the file *org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs*

This is located for example here: *C:\eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\*

Copy and paste over the top of the one in your new eclipse instance. This worked for me when moving from 3.4 to 3.5

Answer (score 3):

I would export the preference before modifying the color, and then after.

That way, you would be able to isolate the specific rules of an eclipse preference file into one smaller file and:

- check if some colors not restored are indeed represented by a rule
- the import of a smaller preference has any effect on the previously unchanged settings.

That kind of strategy can be further refined into several small settings files (one for Java, one for JSP, HTML, CSS, ...), in order to better analyzing the potential side-effects when re-importing those settings.

Comment: How do you export anything else than jre settings and key bindings?
All I get in File->Export->Preferences is jre and key settings.

Comment: On my eclipse 3.4.1 (or 3.5Mx), I do see an 'export all' option I can select. That will... export all preferences. You can then edit the resulting file to keep only what interest you, and re-import those specific setting into your eclipse configuration.

Comment: I think color settings in Eclipse can rarely be isolated to be exported. They are quite separate and cannot be restore by exporting Eclipse preference files. That's why so many ppl vote up this question and so few good answers. This just can be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I have had success in importing Eclipse Helios's syntax highlighting rules by copying the file:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
```

from the source workspace to the target workspace. It seems this file also contains Eclipse's code formatter profiles and code templates.

Environment:

```
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
(on linux)
```

Answer (score 2):

Once Michael Bosworth's answer helped me to some extend and I voted up. But now I see some obligation to answer it myself, because copying these two files are not enough. Let me explain why.

- First, these files contains lines irrevelente to syntax coloring.
- Second, syntax coloring for other editors are located elsewhere, for example, those of XML files are in

  `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.prefs`

and those of `HTML` files:

```
    org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.prefs
```

JSP pages?

```
    org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.prefs
```

, etc.

- Third, when we change font colors, usually we change background colors, line highlighting colors, etc. to get a clearer view of codes. This involves more files.

If we search `*.pref` files in path

```
/workspace/.metadata/.plugins
```

we can find all preferences files where we can locate all lines of coloring settings. But by copy-pasting all these files to another workspace can also trigger problems, for they are not exclusively syntax-coloring-related. Moreover, when we are switching between two versions of Eclipse, unexpected problems may arise.

So, the safest way is:

- Create a new workspace if you don't have one.
- Open all `*.pref` files we find in the workspace one by one,
- Copy those lines containing color codes,
- Find the same file in your new workspace,
- Replace the color part by existing one. Or, set the colors in Eclipse, by assuming the corresponding options according to properties' name. All color codes are RGB based.

**EDIT**: (2017.02.24)

Eclipse Mars has a plugin [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph), which can record your preference settings to provide seamless transmission of your preferences. When you activate it, every time you change a value, it prompts to ask you if you want to record it in Oomph, providing you the exact line in the corresponding file where your new value is stored. So, when you install Oomph, you can:

1. Change the settings of your font face, font size, background color, etc.
2. In the prompt windows of Oomph, take note of the location of your new settings. (Because if you tell Oomph to remember your settings, it will not prompt never again, so you may only see this windows once.)

Comment: Seach in /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings all .pref files are inside this path.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted recently changed *.prefs file from the following dreictory \myworkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\ and imported existing exported preference.

I am the first person, who answer for this question as per my knowledge :), Cause even I struggled lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem few days ago. 
The easiest way to restore the defaults is to import the default theme again, which you can find under:
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=790