# Matching keyword highlight color in editor

Tags: eclipse

I am using a clone of the wombat Vim color scheme in eclipse for Python development and it works well apart from the matching keyword highlight (whatever that is named), which is ffff96. This pale yellow makes it impossible to read the white foreground text. Anyone know where this is set?

Comment: this one is about how to save those prefs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372837/eclipse-syntax-highlighting-preferences-save-and-restore?lq=1

Answer (score 32):

Oh! Found it! General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Occurences(Pydev). Awesome. What a mess.

Comment: Don't forget "Write occurrences" as well

Comment: Yeah I found it too some time ago and than lost xD
Thanks man.

Comment: This location with Michael Mrozek's "Write occurences" (and "Read occurences") did the trick for eclipse-PHP.

Comment: Every time I want to change this, I come back here for help. ... The Eclipse way of changing some random settings.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Paul this is a mess; you have to know the name of what you're looking for in order to find it. Bleh. However, here are actual locations for the underlying settings strings (with thanks to [Frederic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372837/eclipse-syntax-highlighting-preferences-save-and-restore/598146#598146)):

In the file `{Eclipse workspace directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` :

Here are the python-specific and general text colors for matching keywords (they call it "Indication"):

```
pydevOccurrenceIndicationColor=106,105,146
occurrenceIndicationColor=97,97,97
```

Also, if you're looking for a specific value that you can find in the UI but not in a file you can change it in Eclipse to a known RGB value and grep for that in the .settings dir.