# how to change Highlight color of Matching function or other element in zend studio?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, zend-studio, color-scheme

How to change the highlight color of any matching element (function, quote or tag) in Zend Studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution combining 2 similar questions and answers:

[Where to change highlight color for selected occurrences in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699166/where-to-change-highlight-color-in-eclipse)

[Matching keyword highlight color in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862931/matching-keyword-highlight-color-in-editor)

So in Zend Studio you can do it like this:

> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations ->

There you can find different highlight coloring options