# Red Hat jboss Developer studio not opening

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I have been working on Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio for past 3 months. Today I installed the checkstyle plugin and restarted the studio. After which it is not opening the studio, with error `java code return with exitcode = 1`. How can I fix the issue and open JBDS?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly close your Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio then:

- Go to your **`workspace > metadata > plugins`** folder
- Delete the folder: **`org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench`**
- Start Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio again

If not work removing **`org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench`**, remove all folders inside **`plugins`** folder, but this will remove all your preferences and color styles.

#### You can backup some preferences and style files following this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42420328/5626568

---

Another tentative is setting your virtual machine manually.

Go to home folder of Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio, open  **`devstudio.ini`** and add on first line:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/javaw.exe
```